# Measuring vehicle dimensions

Tags: webots

I would like to measure the distance between the rear wheel axis middle point until the driver's seat of the BMW X5 and Citroen CZero models available in WeBots. Can any of you suggest a program to measure such distance, or a way to get it from the PROTO files?

Ps.: Usually one would search this kind of data in technical specs from car manufacturers, but for both vehicles they do not give such detail informations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PROTO file you can easily get the distance between the rear and front axes (look for the value of 'wheelbase', https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/automobile/ackermannvehicle#ackermannvehicle-field-summary).

But for the distance rear axis<->driver seats there is no easy way to get it from the PROTO. The simplest solution is probably to add a box directly in Webots and to make its size match the distance rear axis<->driver seats.